# Compare and Delete in txt files

Tags: text, compare, comparison, applescript

I would like some script or program that compares text documents and which finds the same email address in both texts and makes a new file where the email addresses that only appeared in one of the two stay (the ones that appeared in both files have been deleted in this new text file).

I've tried various comparing programs but they take into account the position and font, etc., etc. My programming is not good enough to change the settings (if this is possible). Maybe something in Applescript? I use a mac...

Example

```
Text1: 

a@mail.x
b@mail.x
c@mail.x
e@mail.x
a@mail.x <--(yes, that's a duplicate... I would like to have them deleted as well)

Text2:

b@mail.x
c@mail.x
a@mail.x
d@mail.x

Text3:

d@mail.x
e@mail.x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way in Excel (Remove Duplicates) that serves my needs.

Thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set compareDocs to choose file with prompt "Select files to compare" with multiple selections allowed

set uniqueItems to {}
repeat with aDoc in compareDocs
    set addresses to paragraphs of (read aDoc as «class utf8»)
    repeat with address in addresses
        set address to contents of address
        if address is not in uniqueItems then
            set end of uniqueItems to address
            set end of uniqueItems to linefeed
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat

set parentFolder to POSIX path of ((first item of compareDocs as text) & "::")
set parentFolder to parentFolder & "Unique_Addresses.txt"

set uniqueItems to uniqueItems as text
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of uniqueItems & " > " & quoted form of parentFolder
```

Comment: I used the example I give as a test and although it does something it doesn't do what I wanted. 
This is the result:

b@mail.x
c@mail.x
a@mail.x
d@mail.x

e@mail.x

Thanks for your quick reply. I hope the solution is near!

Comment: Maybe my example was unclear... I want to compare text 1 with text 2 so that the result will be like text 3